# How to add extra search in orderline[prdocut field]?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In orderline we can search the products based on `name, internal reference and barcode`.I am trying to add one extra field.

Firstly I created a portno field in product template for search

```
port_no_1 = fields.Char(string="Port No")
```

in `product.product` model the

```
name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100)
```

for search products.

How to add this feature in my custom module ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `name_search` method is used to search for a record based on its model's `_rec_name` variable. What you do is override that method, use the value passed to the method `name` and construct your own searches. You make as many searches as you want, create a recordset of the results and then return the appropriate response.

See how this method is overridden in `addons/product/product.py`

You can override the method, call its `super` implementation, get the result and modify it by doing your search and adding the ids.

`ids = self.search(cr, user, args + [('port_no_1', operator, name)], limit=limit, context=context)`